# aosp mirror -after "repo sync", "repo upload" to gerrit fails

Tags: android, repository, gerrit

I have a aosp mirror on a server called git.
I can repo init via ssh:
repo init -u gerrit2@git:mirrors/platform/manifest
then repo sync
The problem is trying upload the changes
repo upload
the upload is to platform/frameworks/base
but in gerrit which has the the projects in mirrors/platform
the project name is  '/frameworks/base'
changing the project name in .repo/manifest.xml to /frameworks/base in client side solves this but this breaks repo sync.

Any advice would be much appriciated

Thanks,
Asi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a terminal, go to the frameworks/base folder and type this command:

```
git config remote.aosp.projectname mirrors/platform/frameworks/base
```

then run `repo upload .`

You can check the git config file at frameworks/base/.git/config
What you are doing is telling git that you have an extra folder: mirrors